# Google Maps - markers not shown

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infowindow

This question is really similar to other questions here, but I could not solve it by reading them all.

I am creating a map, with custom markers with info windows. The problem is, that the markers are not displayed on the map, while the `fitBounds` function is working properly.

Could you please help me, what am I missing?

My code:

```
var home_page_map = null;
function RenderHomePageMap(locations)
{
    var home_page_bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    home_page_map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('home-location-map'), {
        center: {lat: 0.00, lng: 0.00},
        zoom: 8
    });

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(home_page_map, 'idle', function(){

        for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
        {
            if(locations[i]['coords']['longitude'] != '' && locations[i]['coords']['latitude'] != '')
            {
                var coords = new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(locations[i]['coords']['latitude']),
                    parseFloat(locations[i]['coords']['longitude'])
                );

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: home_page_map,
                    position: coords,
                    //icon: ROOT_PATH + 'spa/img/mapmarker.png',
                    title: locations[i]['name'],
                    clickable: true
                });

                home_page_bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());

                marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: ' \
                        <h4 attr-id="'+locations[i]['id']+'">'+locations[i]['name']+'</h4> \
                        <p>'+locations[i]['country']+', '+locations[i]['city']+', '+locations[i]['address']+'</p> \
                    '
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    marker.info.open(home_page_map, marker);
                });
            }
        }

        home_page_map.fitBounds(home_page_bounds);

    });
}
```

Comment: does it also happen with the (currently unset) icon-property?

Comment: are you able to view markers if placed outside the event `idle`? use this to set the center of the map `home_page_map.setCenter(home_page_bounds.getCenter());`

Comment: @Dr.Molle Yes it does.

Comment: @AvantikaSaini No, I tried, but I need that event to make sure the map is already loaded, so the markers will be connected to an existing map.